# Large Table handling

Tags: sql-server

We are having table that contains `6,616,711` (6.6 million) records in it. I want to know, How to manage this table? If there is SO question similar to this please give me link. Having following concern, too.

- How to manage large database?
- What is best system/hardware configuration for this type of scenario?
- Partitioning this table will help us?

Comment: 6.6 million records isn't large... Your system/hardware configuration needs to be dictated by how many (concurrent) users need to access it. Partitioning can help for administrative purposes or if the table mutates a lot.

Comment: How many GB is the table using for data and (nonclustered) index data?  To manage it, start by having a good clustered index, then treat it like every other table.  If it helps, I would consider a 70 million row table to be "medium" size, and a table with 100GB of data perhaps "medium" as well for many SQL Server installations.  Many are much smaller; some are much, much larger - some have a TB of RAM (not disk space, but RAM - i.e. buffer space).  Defrag your indexes when they're too fragmented, watch backup, restore, and CHECKDB times.

Comment: I forgot to ask one thing that. While we are adding new column to this table with default value `0` its taking to much time. Will it take that much time? or we've better option?

Answer (score 1):

Partitioning a table will help you in maintaining.

Here are some useful articles on maintaining a large table:

[Handling Large SQL Server Tables with Data Partitioning](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1200/handling-large-sql-server-tables-with-data-partitioning/)

The only downside is that it only exists in the Enterprise and Developer editions.

[Simplify Database Maintenance with Table Partitions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.03.partitioning.aspx)

And more info on hardware, horizontal, and vertical partitioning:

[Partitioning](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178148%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> Partitioning a database improves performance and simplifies
>   maintenance. By splitting a large table into smaller, individual
>   tables, queries that access only a fraction of the data can run faster
>   because there is less data to scan. Maintenance tasks, such as
>   rebuilding indexes or backing up a table, can run more quickly.
>
> Partitioning can be achieved without splitting tables by physically
>   putting tables on individual disk drives. Putting a table on one
>   physical drive and related tables on a separate drive can improve
>   query performance because, when queries that involve joins between the
>   tables are run, multiple disk heads read data at the same time. SQL
>   Server filegroups can be used to specify on which disks to put the
>   tables.

Also, there are a lot of useful answers in this [thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48176/splitting-a-large-table-to-improve-performance?rq=1)

Hope this helps

Comment: I forgot to ask one thing that. While we are adding new column to this table with default value `0` its taking to much time. Will it take that much time? or we've better option?